# ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable on an existing variable dynamically built

Tags: variables, php-7

First of all thanks for your time on my issue.

Second sorry if this is a duplicate, I legit searched for 3 days on and off and didn't find answer to my particular situation.

[Visual on the error obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pfX5.png)

> This first line transforms an array's values into a string of index(es)

```
$path = self::extract_path($path);
```

> After extraction $path becomes a string with a format similar to['key1']['key2']
>
> Here I test if one valuable element (ondemand) is found within that Keys string, so far so good.

```
if( $path !== FALSE && strpos($path, $element) !== FALSE){

$var_dim_str = 'coupon' . $path . '[recurrence]';
```

> As a self-proofing, I hard-coded one of my specific scenario element and it does exist so my issue is not really non-initialization of my variable as most other topic were suggesting.

```
    var_dump($coupon['item']['ondemand']['recurrence']);
```

> ***My issue lies here, I get "ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: coupon[item][ondemand][recurrence]"***

```
    $recurrence = $$var_dim_str; 

[...]
```

Here are my var_dump output:

These are my indexes as an array they get extracted to reconstruct the variable's string', I have some variable-dimension arrays that gets called so the dimension depth might not always be of fixed value, hence why I have to dynamically test this.

1- $path, before being extracted

```
 [...]\modules\payment\classes\Helper\Payment.php:290:
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'item' (length=4)
      1 => string 'ondemand' (length=8)
```

2- We see here that (['item']['ondemand']['recurrence'] => 3) exists

```
[...]\modules\payment\classes\Payment\Cart.php:266:
array (size=1)
  'item' => 
    array (size=3)
      'ondemand' => 
        array (size=14)
          [...]
          'recurrence' => string '3' (length=1)
      [...]
```

3- My var_dump above is outputting it properly.

```
 [...]\modules\payment\classes\Payment\Cart.php:270:string '3' (length=1)
```

**So, my conclusion is that PHP doesn't really appreciate my 'built' variable but there has to be some way to make this logic work... any pointers on this would be really appreciated. **

Answer (score 0):

The issue does lie with $$var_dim_str. What the $$ does is resolve $$variableName to be the variable name contained in $variableName. It basically holds a reference to another variable *based on the variable's name*. From the PHP site:

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable. In the above example, hello, can be used as the name of a variable by using two dollar signs. i.e.

So ...

```
// some variables
$name = 'Ellan' ;
$site = 'Stack Exchange' ;
$tags = 'PHP-7, Variables' ;

// we want $site
$variableName = 'site' ;
echo $$variableName ;

// we want $tags
$variableName = 'tags' ;
echo $$variableName ;
```

The code above will produce:

> ```
> Stack Exchange
> PHP-7, Variables
> ```

When you assign a value to $var_dim_str:

```
$var_dim_str = 'coupon' . $path . '[recurrence]';
```

$var_dim_str does not hold the name of a variable. It contains the a string.

Are you sure you want to use $$ in this instance? Maybe you really want to use:

```
$recurrence = $var_dim_str;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr Glass.
In fact, I'd like to be able to call my string as if I called this directly:
$coupon['item']['ondemand']['recurrence']

This is the string $var_dim_str contain that I want to call as an array.